# How to restore focus after dismissing a window with Sikuli

Tags: ui-automation, sikuli

Using Sikulix, I thought I'd write a quick script to dismiss a dialog as seamlessly as possible.  So that would mean putting the mouse back where it was and restoring focus to the window that had focus before the dialog was dismissed.  I can't seem to find the right incantation to get focus back to the window that had focus before the action.

```
Settings.MoveMouseDelay = 0

while True:
    wait("1457542434677.png", FOREVER)

    # Save user current state
    aLoc = Env.getMouseLocation()
    aRegion = App.focusedWindow();
    # myApp = ??????

    # dismiss the dialog
    click(Pattern("1457542434677.png").targetOffset(81,33))

    # return to the previous state
    mouseMove(aLoc)
    # myApp.focus()
    sleep(1)
```

The pointer position is restored properly in the code above.  I presume that I've got the Region defined, but can't find a way to get a reference to the App with focus.

Added 3/13: I'm using the current version of SikuliX on Windows 7.
Added 3/17: The "myApp", above, could be any application running on Windows 7.  Could be a browser, could be any other local app.  The dialog I'm dismissing is generated by a non-browser application.

Comment: Still not resolved; I have not been able to retrieve the application that has focus.

Comment: sikuli is being used for app or web ??

Comment: Sikuli is running on Windows 7 viewing apps running on Windows 7.  One such app may be a browser, but I'm not sure why that would make a difference.

Comment: well I had impression that you want focus to set back to browser, but you said its a windows app, you might wana try Auto It.

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of `App` using the programs title, or full path the the executable.  Also, you aren't using the region you created.  Check the fixed code.

```
Settings.MoveMouseDelay = 0

while True:
    wait("1457542434677.png", FOREVER)

    # Save user current state
    aLoc = Env.getMouseLocation()
    aRegion = App.focusedWindow();
    myApp = App('Notepad') # or whatever program title / full path

    # dismiss the dialog
    # use aRegion.click if you want to click within aRegion.
    # aRegion.click(Pattern("1457542434677.png").targetOffset(81,33))
    click(Pattern("1457542434677.png").targetOffset(81,33))

    # return to the previous state
    aRegion.mouseMove(aLoc)
    myApp.focus()
    sleep(1)
```

Depending on the application, you may need to specify the full path to the program instead of just the title.

Comment: Hard-coding the program title does not solve the problem.  Earlier I had mentioned "The "myApp", above, could be any application running on Windows 7. Could be a browser, could be any other local app. "